# function php on script read function

Tags: javascript, php

need help this. 
i nedd load my function on executed this function..............

nedd load `Confirm();`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.demo4').click(function () {
            swal({
                title: "Você tem certeza?",
                text: "Você aprovará a seguinte conta: <?php echo strtoupper($aprovar->nome); ?> <?php echo strtoupper($aprovar->sobrenome); ?>",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Sim, aprovar!",
                cancelButtonText: "Não, cancelar!",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false 
            },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    swal("Aprovado!", "Titular aprovado com sucesso.", "success");
                    Confirm();
                } else {
                    swal("Cancelado", "Aprovação cancelada :)", "error");
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the confirm function

Comment: This code makes no sense to me. You're calling `swal()` with two parameters (an object and an anonymous function), but then within the anonymous function you're again calling `swal()`, but this time with three arguments, all strings.

Comment: função pública Confirmar () {                                                                          
$ data = new stdClass ();                                                                               
$ id = $ this-> uri-> segment (3);                                                                    
$ this-> titular_model-> aprova ($ id);                                                             
}

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/.

In the example of confirm box you can call any function that you want inside the "then" session.. Try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.demo4').click(function () {
            swal({
                title: "Você tem certeza?",
                text: "Você aprovará a seguinte conta: <?php echo strtoupper($aprovar->nome); ?> <?php echo strtoupper($aprovar->sobrenome); ?>",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Sim, aprovar!",
                cancelButtonText: "Não, cancelar!",
            }).then(function () {
                swal("Aprovado!", "Titular aprovado com sucesso.", "success");
                Confirm();
            }, function (dismiss) {
                // dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay',
                // 'close', and 'timer'
                if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
                    swal("Cancelado", "Aprovação cancelada :)", "error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```